# affablebean -with AngularJS cannot implemented with netbeans

Tags: java, angularjs, netbeans

i am  trying to run the affablebean project impelmented -with AngularJS 
On Netbeans Ide 8.0.2
that can be found on here:

https://bitbucket.org/dkonecny/affable-bean

the problem is by defining the libraries that are important to run the server side of the application ,
i have downloaded this library ::`jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar`

and it solved some of the problems  but not all
now i have this problem that the

```
getCriteriaBuilder()
```

founction that belong to `EntityManager()` class
it is cannot be found
so how to solve this?
it shows an error under this function when written with ::

> javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq =
>   getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();

So please help Me!

Comment: `getCriteriaBuilder` was introduced in JPA 2.0. Are your dependencies at least at this version?

Comment: @Reimeus
yes the JPA is 2.0 , the problem is that netbeans showing an error
near this function as it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason was because of the pre-included library that named

`" jersey - persistence 1.0"`

just remove it 
and it will solve the problem !
so the

```
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
```

will give you that there is no error!